# Transformer has continuity but no power on secondary coil

Tags: transformer, repair

Background: Electronics novice, attempting stereo amplifier repair for educational purposes. Amp (Pioneer VSX-519V) blew when the input was removed while at high volume.  Careful visual inspection does not sight any damaged components.

Am in the process of learning how to check a transformer.
The first two wires (black/blue) on primary have continuity, 1.7ohms, and 110v AC is present to the terminals that supply power to the transformer.  There is no voltage present on any of the output terminals.

There is a second set of thick wires from primary coil:  three wires (yellow-red-yellow) that have also proper continuity, but no voltage.

The secondary coils have two groups of three wires, and one group of six wires. Each group has continuity, and expected resistance's, but there is no voltage (AC) present anywhere.

There is no continuity between primary and secondary windings.

--

Question: based on the above, does this transformer have a problem?  I do not presently understand why all the other readings look good, but I have no AC voltage on any secondary windings.

**UPDATE:**

When the transformer is taken out and tested on the bench, it is fine. (that was a good lesson).
When the transformer is installed, something else is "tripping" and cutting power to the transformers primary coil during startup.

Comment: What is the amp? Some readers may have the schematics.

Comment: Pioneer VSX-519V

Comment: Google immediately finds the service manual with schematics.  That should help you to proceed. I have repaired a similar model to this. I needed to replace the thermal fuse inside the main power transformer, which required removal of the insulating tape. I mention this so that you don't overlook it, not to say that it is definitely your problem too.

Comment: Are you measuring the secondaries under load? Or opened?

Comment: Opened - had just unplugged them from the main board and put a multimeter on the pins. Amp doesn't power on at all.

Comment: I found the service manual with the google search 'pioneer vsx-519v service manual', at https://elektrotanya.com/pioneer_vsx-519v-k_sm.pdf/download.html

Comment: When you say the amp does not power on at all, do you mean that even the standby supply is not working? These products have soft power switches, and you should hear the relay clicking on attempted power on. If the startup tests fail, it should turn off again (and click), if memory serves, about 200ms later.

Comment: @replete Thanks for the manual. Correct, not even standby, dead as a doornail. IF I try reset mode (holding down power and Surround) then, and only then, do I hear a relay click. A few seconds later it just clicks back off. Nothing appears on screen at all.

Comment: By standby I did not mean that you should expect anything on the display, as the filament display supply is derived from the main power transformer not the standby supply transformer. The standby supply powers the main logic IC on the other side of the unit which performs startup tests and drives the mains input relay. Good luck in your repair, it should be a great learning experience.

Comment: The 2nd pair of thick wires is likely the 250V with center tap for the amp section. Connector CP101 to the two huge caps right?

Comment: Yep thats right, CP101. So is that step-up coil? from 110v to 250v? I have 110v in, but no power 250v out on CP101. So does that mean there is indeed a problem with the transformer?

Comment: If the thermal fuse has blown inside the transformer, then wouldn't it show open circuit on at least one of the coils?

Comment: Your update about the transformer being removed from the circuit on startup was exactly what I was referring to with my comments above about the startup sequence. Either the controller is driving the relay to disconnect it so you have a problem downstream, which could take some time to find, or there is a problem upstream which should be quick to find. Do you have a scope?

Comment: I can quickly obtain a scope, friend has one, although i wouldn't know where to start using it in this context?

Comment: @replete Followed the flowchat on page 26 - passes 2A, fails 2B - instructions are simply "diagnose main assembly". Trying my best, any pointers on where to begin appreciated. Transformer is fine, nothing visually damaged.

Comment: I found two slightly suspicious looking diodes, that measure 0.6 one way, and 0.7 the other - does that suggest they have shorted open?

Comment: Where to begin: where power enters the board. Where to go next: where power does. Give the schematic reference for the diodes, yes they're almost certainly shorted.

Comment: Thanks. Ill get there :).. D301 & D302. Page 52 grid reference E1.5. They go to the relay that provides power to the power transformer

Comment: @replete You have effectively answered my question, that the real solution is to check the power transformer is indeed getting 110v _when in circuit) (& test it on the bench) - i.e you pointed me towards the standby supply circuit which is tripping & cutting supply to the power trans - I am unable to accept a comment as an answer, requesting please post as an answer to help the next newbie that comes across this.

Comment: Those diodes are in series. It is to be expected that one will see a diode drop across it. Also they are not at all in a high energy path when the amplifier is overstressed. This is not likely to be the fault. Follow the base of Q301 (nearby) on the schematic and you will understand what is happening. The protection circuit (abbreviation P/T) is rejecting something during startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your update tells me that your initial statement "...110V Ac is present to the terminals that supply power to the transformer..." is misleading. It implies that you are measuring **at the transformer** terminals - which you are not.
It is clear to me, that there is some safety circuit between the **board terminals** (were 110V comes in), and the **transformer's** input terminals.
Your safety circuit is detecting an unsafe condition and disabling power to the transformer primary terminals.
There is nothing wrong with the transformer.  Most likely, your power output transistors are shorted/blown, causing the safety circuit to remove power to the transformer.

Comment: Thats essentially correct. I was measuring the terminals where the transformer connects to the board (with the transformer unplugged, so I could reach the pins). 110v AC was present on the "transformer input pins".  What I didn't realise was that plugging the transformer back in was resulting in power being cut to those same pins - because of the safety circuit as you point out.  Good learning experience.